# Class with static array class in C++

Tags: c++

I not sure why this the static array is not matching the declaration, I feel like I'm forgetting something to make this work and I'm racking my brain for what it might be and my searches don't bring up anything useful.

```
class ExampleClass 
{
public:
   ExampleClass(int x, int y)
   {
      a = x;
      b = y;
   }
private:
   int a;
   int b;   
}

class A_Class
{
public :
   static ExampleClass arr [2];
}
ExampleClass A_Class:: arr = { ExampleClass(1,2), ExampleClass(3,4) };// Error : incompatible with declaration
```

Thanks in advance

sorry for the typo arr is declared as a ExampleClass in the running code

Comment: Fix your syntax/logic/type errors? [Example](http://pastebin.com/hbddWAe9). There is no `Example` class, neither of your classes are finished with a semi-colon, the array dimension syntax `[2]` is not specified on the definition. etc.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to learn to use constructor initialization lists to initialize member variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `A_Class::arr` as an array of `ExampleClass`, but you're trying to define it as if it had the type `Example`. That's a different type:

```
ExampleClass A_Class::arr
 [2]  // <- this is the problem
 = { ExampleClass(1,2), ExampleClass(3,4)} ;
```